# Python class condition: getting an [x,x] output from an x input?

Tags: python

I'm playing around with some interval calculations in Python. This is an excerpt of what I've written. I want to include degenerate intervals i.e. the interval for the real number 1 is [1,1].

So when I type Interval(1), I want [1,1] returned. But I've defined my interval class in terms of two parameters.

I can't make a subclass - it would still expect two parameters. Can anyone point me in the right direction please? Could I extend the __contains__ in some sense?

**TLDR**: How can I get an [x,x] output from an x input?

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

class Interval:
    def __init__(self, LeftEndpoint, RightEndpoint):
        self.min = LeftEndpoint
        self.max = RightEndpoint
        if LeftEndpoint > RightEndpoint:
            raise ValueError('LeftEndpoint must not be greater than RightEndpoint') 

    def __repr__(self): #TASK 3
        return '[{},{}]'.format(self.min,self.max)

    def __contains__(self, num):
        if num < self.min:
            raise Exception('The number is not in the given interval')
        if num > self.max:
            raise Exception('The number is not in the given interval')

p = Interval(1,2)
print(p) #returns [1,2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give `RightEndpoint` a default value, like `None`; if it is still `None` in the function, you know no value was assigned to it and thus can be set to the same value as `LeftEndpoint`:

```
def __init__(self, LeftEndpoint, RightEndpoint=None):
    if RightEndpoint is None:
        RightEndpoint = LeftEndpoint
```

Note: if you follow the [Python styleguide, PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), parameter and local variable names should be all lowercase_with_underscores. And the `__contains__` method should really return `True` or `False`, not raise an exception:

```
class Interval:
    def __init__(self, left, right=None):
        if right is None:
            right = left
        if left > right:
            raise ValueError(
                'left must not be greater than right')
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'[{self.left}, {self.right}]'

    def __contains__(self, num):
        return self.left <= num <= self.right
```

Note that the `__contains__` method can now be expressed as a single test; either `num` is in the (inclusive) range of `left` to `right`, or it is not.

Demo:

```
>>> Interval(1, 2)
[1, 2]
>>> Interval(1)
[1, 1]
>>> 11 in Interval(42, 81)
False
>>> 55 in Interval(42, 81)
True
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried all that except I didn't set it equal to None at the start. Great answer, thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `*args` to pass in a variable number of arguments, then just assign `RightEndpoint` dynamically:

```
def __init__(self, *args):
        self.min = args[0]
        if len(args) < 2:
            RightEndpoint = args[0]
        elif len(args) == 2:
            RightEndpoint = args[1]
        else:
            # decide what to do with more than 2 inputs
        self.max = RightEndpoint
        #...


p = Interval(1,2)
print(p) #returns [1,2]
p1 = Interval(1) 
print(p1) #returns [1,1]
```

(Alternately you can use `**kwargs` if you want to use keyword arguments instead.)

Comment: Only use that if you need to support an arbitrary number of values. For 1 or two, this is overkill and now requires you to handle the case where `len(args) > 2`, which doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Martijn Pieters - I guess I've just grown wary of using default parameters in my own code, as it's easy for me to lose track of them when I'm not forced to call them.  So I'd rather have a variadic set where I account for the possible inputs inside a class/function, or specify arguments explicitly, instead of relying on defaults.  Any advice you can give on this perspective?

Comment: Get a better editor then, one that understands Python code to show you parameters when auto-completing or inspecting code. Using `*args` makes it much harder for such tools to help you analyse your code.